# unable to send large file using ssh2_scp_send() function

Tags: php, libssh2

I am using ssh2_scp_send() function to send files on my server. small file with size(less than 10mb) I am able to send successfully but if the file size is greater than 10 mb then it is giving error :

```
ssh2_scp_send(): Failed copying file in (...)
```

and file is not going on server. is there any configuration variable I need to change?

Comment: Does the scp work for >10Mb files if you do it at the command line, not via PHP?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using SCP instead of SFTP? If not then does it work with SFTP?

Comment: @madebydavid : Yes, SCP work for >10mb files through command line.

Comment: @neubert : I want to make file transfer secure  because of that reason  I am using SCP.as > 10mb file is not transferring using ssh2_scp_send()function then I am using fwrite() to transfer file with  "ssh.sftp" protocol in following ways:
$sftpStream   = fopen("ssh2.sftp://filepath, 'w');  //open destination file
and then writing content in to above file using fwrite(sftpStream,$contents).
using fwrite(),I am able to send file which has size more than 10mb as well. just want to confirm is that secure File transfer over SCP?
thank you.

Comment: check your PHP Ssh2 extention version.libssh2 version 1.7.0 is ok.
I met this problem when libssh2's version is 1.2.2.